# Missing HIDs from Teams

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, embedded-linux, microsoft-teams, hid

I'm developing a USB HID device that interfaces with Teams.

The issue:
I get ring-HID for Incoming Teams call, but when I accept the call from the host-- I don't get the hook-off HID, nor any other HID from the same usage-page, like mute or hold.

Details:

1. Using pywinusb (from the same windows10 host), I'm able to receive all HIDs.
2. Using Wireshark to sniff usb-- I don't see the off-hook HID from Teams, so I can assume it simply "decides" not to send it to my device.

Now, Teams is a real blackbox for me, but I wonder whether anyone has some insights into that (maybe relevant Teams-dev || someone that encountered this issue is the past || fw-dev for Teams-compliant device).

The relevant device's HID report descriptor usage page looks like this:

```
Usage Page (LEDs)   05 08 
Logical Minimum (0) 15 00 
Logical Maximum (1) 25 01 
Usage (Off-Hook)    09 17 
Usage (Mute)    09 09 
Usage (Ring)    09 18 
Usage (Hold)    09 20 
Usage (Microphone)  09 21 
Report Size (1) 75 01 
Report Count (5)    95 05 
Output (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,NPrf,NNul,NVol,Bit)   91 22
```

EDIT:

The device uses Android OS, using linux usb gadget function f_hid via configfs. For this reason I decided to add the linux-related tags.

Comment: Could you please raise product related queries to [Microsoft teams product channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback#product-support-channels)?

Comment: Can you add the type of device or functionality that your are developing? There is a team's certification for some device classes, and AFAIK most signals are  sent  tot certified devices only